# Title for the icons in per-site and per-site meta

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, hyperlinks, favicon

When hover the **icons** of the Meta User and Main User in the profile page on per-site and per-site meta, I see the title as **meta site favicon** and **parent site favicon**. These titles are applied only for icons not for the links.

For the Stack Exchange profile also the same issue occurred. After inspect the element I see the `title` is applied for the icon div only.

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar">
    <div class="favicon favicon-stackexchange" title="stack exchange network profile"></div>
    Network Profile
</a>
```

My Questions are:

1. Why the `title` is applied only for icon div, not for the `<a>` ?
2. Do we need the titles for the icons (*meta site favicon / parent site favicon*) ?

Screenshot taken from the SO site, but the same happened for all SE sites.

<sup>**Note:** I can't take the screenshot with hand cursor, so I added arrow mark instead</sup>

> [image: Title for the icons]

Comment: I believe this ..situation is still the same. Why is this being closed now as "no longer reproducible"?